# $O(n)$ is a closed subset of $U(n)$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, lie-groups

I want to show that $O(n)$ is a closed subgroup of $U(n)$. I am by confused since $U(n)$ lives in $\text{Mat}(\mathbb C,n)$ and $O(n)$ lives in $\text{Mat}(\mathbb R,n)$. It is not to hard to show that $O(n)$ is a subgroup, but I can't see why it is closed as a topological space.

To show that $O(n)$ is a subgroup of $U(n)$. There is a natural way in which $\text{Mat}(\mathbb R,n)$ lives in $\text{Mat}(\mathbb C,n)$. If $O\in O(n)$ then $OO^T=I$, but also $O^{*}=O^T$, so $O\in U(n)$.

Comment: Could you write $O(n) = \operatorname{Mat}(\mathbb{R}, n) \cap U(n)$, the intersection of two closed sets inside $\operatorname{Mat}(\mathbb{C}, n)$?

Comment: Joppy's suggestion is very good. Another idea is to use the definition of $O(n)$ that says, as you write that $O^TO = I$ for all $O \in O(n)$. In other words: $O(n)$ is the inverse image of the set $\{I\}$ under the map $f: A \mapsto A^TA$. In many situations a good way of showing that a set is closed is to recognize it as the inverse image of another closed set under a continuous map. So here we only need that $f$ is continuous and the one point set $\{I\}$ is closed. That seems doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual interpretation of $\mathbb R$ as a *genuine subfield* of $\mathbb C$ allows us to regard $\text{Mat}(\mathbb R,n)$ as a genuine subset of $\text{Mat}(\mathbb C,n)$. Both spaces are vector spaces over $\mathbb R$  which have a natural topology induced by any norm. Thus $\text{Mat}(\mathbb R,n)$ is a both a linear and a topological subsapce of $\text{Mat}(\mathbb C,n)$, and $\text{Mat}(\mathbb R,n)$ is obviously closed in $\text{Mat}(\mathbb C,n)$.

But now
$$O(n) = U(n) \cap \text{Mat}(\mathbb R,n)$$
which is a closed subset of $U(n)$.